# WideCharToMultiByte when is lpUsedDefaultChar true?

Tags: windows, winapi, unicode, mfc

I am trying to understand WideCharToMultiByte and I was wondering when lpUsedDefaultChar would be set to be TRUE.

Here is a sample: What should be lpszW inorder for the flag to be set to be true?

```
lpszW = L”__WHAT SHOULD_BE_HERE__”;
int c = ??;
BOOL fUsedDefaultChar = false;
DWORD dwSize = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_ACP, 0, lpszW,  c, myOutStr ,myOutLen, NULL, &fUsedDefaultChar);
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd374130(VS.85).aspx

Any books/tutorials for understanding Unicode/UTF stuff would be great.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Anything that is not present in the current codepage will map to ? (by default) and UsedDefaultChar will be != FALSE.

[Windows-1252](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) is probably the most common codepage and most of those characters [map to the same value](http://www.unicode.org/Public/MAPPINGS/VENDORS/MICSFT/WINDOWS/CP1252.TXT) in unicode.

Take [Ω (ohm)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2126/index.htm#OHM) for example, it is probably not present in whatever your current codepage is and therefore will not map to a valid narrow character:

```
BOOL fUsedDefaultChar=FALSE;
DWORD dwSize;
char myOutStr[MAX_PATH];
WCHAR lpszW[10]=L"Hello";
*lpszW=0x2126; //ohm sign, you could also use the \u2126 syntax if your compiler supports it.
dwSize = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_ACP, 0, lpszW,  -1, myOutStr ,MAX_PATH, NULL, &fUsedDefaultChar); 
printf("%d %s\n",fUsedDefaultChar,myOutStr); //This prints "1 ?ello" on my system
```

Comment: Thanks Anders, I should have framed this question better. If I pass in a string L"abc\x0100" I still get fUsedDefaultChar == true. What is the exact range?

Comment: @tvr: There is no exact range since it depends on the codepage you are converting to, but anything <= 127 should be safe.

Answer (score 1):

The [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd374130%28VS.85%29.aspx) is very clear about when `lpUsedDefaultChar` is set to TRUE:

> lpDefaultChar [in] Optional. Pointer
>   to the character to use if a character
>   cannot be represented in the specified
>   code page. The application sets this
>   parameter to NULL if the function is
>   to use a system default value. To
>   obtain the system default character,
>   the application can call the GetCPInfo
>   or GetCPInfoEx function.
>
> lpUsedDefaultChar [out] Optional.
>   Pointer to a flag that indicates if
>   the function has used a default
>   character in the conversion. The flag
>   is set to TRUE if one or more
>   characters in the source string cannot
>   be represented in the specified code
>   page. Otherwise, the flag is set to
>   FALSE. This parameter can be set to
>   NULL.

That does not leave much room for misunderstanding, in my opinion.